# <file>-Info.plist couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I Have an issue on my xcode project, some times when I build my project the follow issue appears for some files:
[image]

To fix sometimes this issue I clean the project, or delete temporary files(but not always it works), and the project run successfully, but there are moments that xcode keep showing this issue but I spend a lot of time trying to fix it.

do you know what is the reason of this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. My partial solution is described below:

- Product > Clean the project
- Delete the build directory:
  [image: Delete]
- Product > Build For > Testing
- Product > Build

It's the better solution that I have found. Although tedious.

Best regards :)

Comment: Crazy stuff, clean in xcode means cleaning and delete deriveddata ;)

Comment: Not completely, some files aren't deleted after clean. :( Even now with Xcode 7.3